# EJB SessionBean - combination of @TransactionManagement and @TransactionAttribute

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, ejb

am I right that combination of @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN) with any settings of @TransactionAttribute on SessionBean has no sense?

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
@TransactionAttribute([any possible value of TransactionAttributeType])
public class SomeSessionBean {
    ....
}
```

I cannot find this in any documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttribute.html

> The TransactionAttribute annotation
>   specifies whether the container is to
>   invoke a business method within a
>   transaction context. The
>   TransactionAttribute annotation can be
>   used for session beans and message
>   driven beans. **It can only be specified
>   if container managed transaction
>   demarcation is used.**

Comment: I should be ashamed not to look into API. Thank you.

Comment: I spent 5-10 minutes searching through the spec and couldn't find anything until it occured to me to check the javadoc :-).